# Magento 2.3 - Show Label after Input in Form Field

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

How can I change the order of form field elements so that the label is directly after the input field? (so I can use css sibling selectors)

I've tried this guide, but no luck, cleared cache, deployed, etc.
https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Remove-Label-and-Edit-PlaceHolder-in-Checkout-Page/td-p/106707

Specifically I am trying to do this for the billing address fields in the checkout.

Which files do I need to override?
This?

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address/form.html